# PostgreSQL Stored Procedure stops functioning abruptly

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL works perfectly fine on a schedule. However, after an 'x' number of days, it stops functioning correctly. 'x' is an indeterminate variable which ranges between 3 and 90 as far as we've noticed. Once it 'breaks' and populates the table incorrectly, it continues to behave this way on future scheduled runs until the next time it is executed manually.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.4. I can post the code for the SP but it definitely works just fine until something makes it break.

Any ideas what it might be and how I may be able to fix it?

**Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_oppscreated()
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bec_oppscreated CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE bec_oppscreated WITH (OIDS=TRUE)
AS

SELECT opportunity.id AS oppid,
   SPLIT_PART(user2.username, '@', 1) AS username,
   recordtype.name AS opptype,
   opportunity.stagename AS stage,
   opportunity.createddate AS createddate,
   opportunity.ve__c AS ve,
   opportunity.amount AS oppamount,
   opportunity.lab AS lab,

   CASE
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Proposal' AND opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN opportunity.amount
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Proposal' AND opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN opportunity.lab
          ELSE 0
   END AS amount_prp_created,
   CASE
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Amendment' AND opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN opportunity.amount
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Amendment' AND opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN opportunity.lab
          ELSE 0
   END AS amount_amd_created,
   CASE
          WHEN (opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN opportunity.amount
          WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN opportunity.lab
          ELSE 0
   END AS amount_cons_created,

   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'A') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_A_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'C') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_C_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'D') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_D_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'I') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_I_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'L') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_L_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'M') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_M_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'P') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_P_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'V') THEN opportunity.amount ELSE 0 END AS amount_V_created,
   opportunity.amount AS amount_created,

   CASE
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Proposal' AND opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN 1
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Proposal' AND opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
   END AS count_prp_created,
   CASE
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Amendment' AND opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN 1
          WHEN (recordtype.name = 'Amendment' AND opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
   END AS count_amd_created,
   CASE
          WHEN (opportunity.ve__c <> 'V') THEN 1
          WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'V' AND opportunity.lab <> 0 AND opportunity.lab IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
   END AS count_cons_created,

   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_A_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_C_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'D') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_D_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'I') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_I_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'L') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_L_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'M') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_M_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'P') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_P_created,
   CASE WHEN (opportunity.ve__c = 'V') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_V_created,
   1 AS count_created
FROM opportunity
LEFT JOIN user2 ON opportunity.ownerid = user2.id
LEFT JOIN recordtype ON opportunity.recordtypeid = recordtype.id
WHERE opportunity.isdeleted = FALSE
AND   opportunity.createddate > '2007-11-02 03:59:59'
AND   opportunity.lastmodifieddate > '2010-01-11 04:59:59'
ORDER BY username ASC;

GRANT SELECT
ON bec_oppscreated
TO public;
RETURN 0;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
BEGIN
RAISE notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
             'Transaction was rolled back';

RAISE notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
RETURN -1;
END;

END;
$function$
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Define "works perfectly fine on a schedule". What "schedule"?

Comment: Is it the SELECT that goes wrong? And what goes wrong?

Comment: Schedule - cronjob set up to run the procedure every 10 minutes.

Comment: What goes wrong is that the table that it's supposed to create called 'sp_oppscreated' gets partially and incorrectly populated. I don't think it's something wrong with the code itself, since the code executes perfectly fine on most runs except when it 'breaks'.

Comment: And you're 200% sure there is nothing wrong with your data? Dropping and creating tables is error prone, multiple processes might execute these statements without noticing and you only see the results of the last one.

Comment: I am 200% sure that nothing is wrong with the data. When I look at a table that was run just a minute ago, it is incorrect, and after running the SP manually, it is correct - all without the source data changing.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to cron.

For whatever reason, the postgres user loses ability to access `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` so that all commands executed from cron result in "command not found" including `/bin/bash --version`.

`*/5 * * * * postgres /bin/bash --version >> /var/log/mylog 2>&1`

Entry in /var/log/mylog:
`/bin/bash: postgres: command not found`

This occurs even with SHELL=/bin/bash.

Took the following actions, each time monitoring the logs. 
- Added PATH statement to the postgres user crontab. Did not fix.
- Restarted /etc/init.d/crond. Did not fix.
- Moved command to root user crontab. Did not fix.
- Moved the cronjob to cron.hourly. FIXED!